# ASP.NET Identity not set in login request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using ASP.NET identity with a `ClaimsIdentity` to authenticate my users. When a user is authenticated, the property `User.Identity` contains a `ClaimsIdentity` instance.

However, this is not the case during the Login request:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var identity = User.Identity;

------------>   // identity is of type WindowsIdentity  <------------

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

As you can see, even though the login was successful, the property `User.Identity` is not yet set to the `ClaimsIdentity` instance. I think this is plausible, it means that the `SignInManager` does not update the property, so we have to wait until the next request to see the result of the login.

**However, I have to do additional logic after the method `PasswordSignInAsync`, so I need a way to get the `ClaimsIdentity` instance in the *.Success* branch of the switch statement.**

While inspecting the `SignInManager` in the debugger, I saw that it is of type `Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager`, which has the property `SignInEntry.Item1` which contains the `ClaimsIdentity` I'm looking for.

However, the type `Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager` is not public, so the only way seems to be a hack using reflection.

**Is there an better way?**

Comment: Use `RedirectToAction` and get the identity in that action? Rather than returning a URL, return the name of the view you want to redirect to.

Comment: That's the workaround I'm using at the moment. But isn't it possible to get the `ClaimsIdentity` in the Login action?

Comment: [Apparently not.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26739821/3846058)

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it's too bad that the PasswordSignInAsync doesn't return the user instance as an out parameter. If you look the source code, you can see that it uses `this.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName)` to find the user by userName, and then uses `this.UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password)` to validate the password, but the user is stored in a local variable.

I think this should be proposed as an improvement to the SignInManager class.

A possible (and inefficient) workaround is to query for the user again and then create the claims identity yourselft in the same way SignInManager.SignInAsync does:

```
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await SignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 7):

The identity is exposed through the `AuthenticationResponseGrant` property:

```
ClaimsIdentity identity = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me and I believe it does not have the inefficiency involved in Augusto's answer (which was my first inclination).  I would propose making this the accepted answer.