# Asp.Net logging, IIS, getting current user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am having some major issues when it comes to getting the current username of the account signed on using Asp.Net's default logging system and 
`WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)` seems to work correctly.

The problem is a non-issue when debugging locally, but now I am at a point where I am deploying to IIS.  I have tested several ways to get the logged in user, but to no avail.  What I have tried are:

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
 System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
 System.Environment.UserName
 HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
 WebSecurity.CurrentUserName
```

With Results -

CORP\bsmith

IIS APPPOOL\SecondaryAppTest

SecondaryAppTest

CORP\bsmith

CORP\bsmith

None of these are the username of the successful logged in individual username "aaa@gmail.com"

I have also updated my web.config to set impersonation to false and authentication mode to forms as well as windows.

Can anyone tell me how to get the correct username, provided a successful login when deployed to IIS?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739778/get-userid-of-logged-in-user-in-asp-net-mvc-5) can be your solution or 
 if you open your **_LoginPartial.cshtml** under **Views/Shared** folder you will get following "**User.Identity.GetUserName()**" which give login in user name.

Answer (score 0):

if you deploy on iis and you config the webconfig `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`  you will get the computer name.
But if you set in your application a **Anonymous access** to disabled and only **Integrated Windows Authentication** in IIS
you get user account run the asp.net 
and if you add `<identity impersonate ="true"/>` i think you get the window account name
i read it somewhere just dont remember where is the post.