# How to get logged UserID in asp.net MVC and display it in hidden text box

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can get username using @user.identity.name from table user but i need to get UserID instead of Username. how to do it?. i tried the following code in my controller but it returns 0.

**My Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        User currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == userId);
        ViewBag.UID=userId;
        return View();
    }
```

**My View**

```
 <input value="@ViewBag.UID" type="hidden"/>
```

**My Model**

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    //added by zakerr
    public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength =4)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Status { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739778/get-userid-of-logged-in-user-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: i am not using asp.net membersing

Comment: If you are using your own membership provider, you probably should add your own method(s) to get the correct logged in user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't about ASP.NET membership, then you should be using your own method and query to do so as follows: (I guess, you are passing email for the login)

```
int currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == email).Select(x => x.userId);
ViewBag.UID = Convert.ToInt32(userId);
```

Comment: string uname = User.Identity.Name;
            int currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username ==uname).Select(x => x.UserID);
            ViewBag.UID = Convert.ToInt32(uname);

Comment: in this case the error is implicitly can not covert int to int ' int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            int currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserID==userId).Select(x => x.UserID);
            ViewBag.UID = Convert.ToInt32(userId);'

Comment: What's the error? You should pass currentUser, not uname in the ViewBag.

Comment: can to write the complete code incase of passing username for the login??

Comment: You are almost done. Do this - string uname = User.Identity.Name; int currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username ==uname).Select(x => x.UserID); ViewBag.UID = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser);

Comment: i did but the error is still  " can not implicitly convert type '<system.Linq.IQuerable<int>' to 'int'

Comment: OK. That's another issue. Do one thing - Take the name input like this: <input type="text" name="username" /> Then in Linq, do this: string
uname = Request.Form["username"].ToString(); int
currentUser = db.Users.Where(x => x.Username ==uname).Select(x => x.UserID); ViewBag.UID =
Convert.ToInt32(currentUser); See what happenss?

Comment: I am changing the Linq. See this helps: int currentUser = (from c in db.Users Where c.Username == uname Select c.userId).ToList(); ViewBag.ID = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser);

Comment: it says a query body must end with a select clause or a group clasue

Comment: My fault. Check this now - int currentUser = (from c in db.Users Where c.Username == uname Select new { c.userId }).ToList(); ViewBag.ID =
Convert.ToInt32(currentUser);

Comment: can not implicitly convert type '<system.collections.generic.list<Anonymouse type#1>' to 'int'

Comment: while i change int currentUser to var currentUser and VieBage.ID =currntUser the error gone but return null

Comment: Are you sure that's null? Put breakpoint and see any value passed or not. Otherwise, try to use session instead of ViewBag like this Session["ID"] = Convert.Toint32(currentUser). Then in the next view, use this - @Session["ID"]

Comment: Yes i am sure the return value is null

Comment: the value for cuurentUser is null, for uname  is OK it return administrator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124784/discussion-between-at-2016-and-user3340320).

Comment: i found the solution :

Comment: string uname = User.Identity.Name;
            var obj= db.Users.Where(x => x.Username.Equals(uname)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (obj != null)
            {
                int userID = obj.UserID;
                ViewBag.UID = userID;
            }

Comment: the above is the solution, thanks for your reply  AT-2016.

Comment: Good one. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

It should return UserIdid

```
string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
```

Comment: Its nothing but user

Comment: i am not using asp.net membership, in my case its like

Comment: string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
User currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == currentUserId);

Comment: Then you should maintain current user in Info in session

Comment: You can user like this

Comment: `public static Int32 UserID
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
                    return (Int32)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"];
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = value;
            }
        }`

Comment: fill while logging