# how to prevent user login with same account in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to prevent multiple login for user with same username and password . Example :

User A login with account "A", Session["AccountA"] is create ( about 30 minutes ) . After user B login with account "A" ,Session["AccountA"] is create and Session["AccountA"] of user A timeout .

Comment: Don't use Session for account

Comment: So what should i do ?

Comment: You shouldn't prevent user login with multiple times in multiple browsers.But you can check user is login or not (`if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {}`), and get current user id ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26739821/5606916)). Also, you can use `[Authorize]/[AllowAnonymous]` attributes in your controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (although may not be as great an idea as you are thinking).  Here's one way to do it:

When the user signs on, store a value in Application state that binds his session ID to his user ID.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var lookup = String.Format("Session_{0}", userID);
Application.Lock();
Application[lookup] = context.Session.SessionID;
Application.Unlock();
```

When a user requests a page (and is not signing on) check to see if the binding is correct.  If not, kill the session.

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;
var lookup = String.Format("Session_{0}", userID);
var sessionID = Application[lookup] as string;
if (sessionID != context.Session.SessionID)
{
    context.Session.Abandon();
    var c = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,"DELETED");
    c.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
    context.Response.AppendCookie(c);
    context.Response.Redirect("~/logout.aspx");
}
```

When a user attempts to access a page, but has the wrong session ID, his session will be killed.

The trick here is... your Application state will keep growing as users sign on.  You will need to devise some means of detecting when users have signed off and cleaning it up, or you will need to recycle your AppPool on a regular basis.